# How to send XCM message from parachain to solochain via the parity bridge

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, parachain

I am quite new to substrate and polkadot parachains. I am trying to bridge a parachain and a solochain using the  [substrate bridge repo](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common)

1. Is it possible to send arbitrary data from the para chain to the solochain via theabove bridge using XCM or call an extrinsic on the solo chain from the parachain ?
2. how do I use MultiLocation to send data from the para chain to the solochain currently what would be the Location of the bridge / solochain and I can send the xcm message ?
3. Is there a guide or example for this?